# Google Extensions: Tab Events - changing windows?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, event-handling

I have written an extension, which changing his icon on websites, who matches the if clause.
Take a look:

```
chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(
    function (activeInfo) {
            chrome.tabs.get(activeInfo.tabId, function(tab){
                hosterRegExp(tab.url); //Function to change Icon

        });     
    }
);

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(
    function checkHosts(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
        hosterRegExp(tab.url); //Function to change Icon
}
);
```

Every time the active tab is changed or a tab is getting reloaded the function hosterRegExp is called with the current URL. This works fine.

Now, that's not working with two windows. If I change between two windows, it doesn't call the hosterRegExp(); that's because the active tab is not reloaded nor is it changing the active tab.

Also I couldn't find another EventHandler which would help me.
So I have to check also the current windowID? I don't know - please help me.

Thank you.

Comment: [`chrome.windows.onFocusChanged`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows.html#event-onFocusChanged)

Comment: Did you try using the optional tabId field in the details parameter of the `chrome.browserAction.setIcon`? That way you would only need to set the icon on tab updates, not on tab or window focus changes.

Comment: @rsanchez: I will do more than set the Icon, that was just an example..I will try to get a solution via onFocusChanged.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like RobW told me, I'm using the

```
  chrome.windows.onFocusChanged
```

API now.

Well, in my case it will look like this:

```
chrome.windows.onFocusChanged.addListener(function() 
{
    chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: true}, function(tab)
    {
        hosterRegExp(tab[0].url);
    }); 
});
```

I used the query method to get the tab after the changed focus. Though it isn't possible that 2 tabs are active in one window, the array has everytime only one element.

That's not beautiful, if someone has a better and cleaner code, tell me!